# How to appropriate use request in python to get Facebook data?

Tags: python, facebook, request, web-crawler

I am writhing code in python to crawl Facebook data, I found one example in web but it seems not appropriate for my purpose, the main problem is in request sentence, here is the code:

```
x= g.request('search', {'q' : 'TaylorSwift', 'type' : 'page', 'limit' : 10})['data'][0]['id']
```

Does somebody know what's the means of this request and tell me how to modify it?

Comment: If you want get data from facebook the best point to start reading is https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api . Crawling Facebook is not allowed, you will hard get any help with it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `g.request('search', {'q' : 'TaylorSwift', 'type' : 'page', 'limit' : 10})`

That’s just a request to the search endpoint, and what you can search for and with what parameters, is described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4#search

Comment: Thank you very much, I want to search by group so how can I modify it?

Comment: You change the value of the `type` parameter perhaps …?

Comment: I try it, but it seems not work, a little weird, so do you know other idea?

Comment: I’d suggest you try your request in Graph API Explorer first – and once you get the results you want there, you translate it into the parameters your framework is expecting.